# HDP: How to change HADOOP_CLASSPATH value

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform

I need to add a value to the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` environment variable, according to this troubleshoot article: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.2/bk_installing_manually_book/content/troubleshooting-phoenix.html

when I type `echo $HADOOP_CLASSPATH` in console I get an empty result back. I think I need to set these values in an config.xml file...

Where or how can I set this new value to the environment variable?

Can I set it in `spark-submit`?

Comment: Did you check Hadoop's `hadoop-env.sh` script in your Hadoop installation (should be in `/etc/hadoop` directory) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error can be avoided by adding the jar path to the `spark-submit` call via `--driver-class-path` parameter:

```
 spark-submit --class sparkhbase.PhoenixTest --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-class-path "/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar" /home/test/app.jar
```

It also worked by setting the `--conf` parameter like this:

```
spark-submit --class sparkhbase.PhoenixTest --master yarn --deploy-mode client --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar" /home/test/app.jar
```

Setting ONE of them should do it!

Also add `--conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.2.4.2.0-258.jar"` to your `spark-submit` if you still get an exception (can happen when code is launched on the executors, not on master)

Answer (score 0):

You can add environment variable  HADOOP_CONF_DIR in spark-env.sh so whenever you run spark-submit it will automatically pick all environment variable. this environment variable value is path of hadoop configuration.

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR = to point Spark towards Hadoop configuration files